# CSS alignment cross browser

Tags: css, cross-browser, alignment

I've created a counter with 4 digits, which need to be displayed in the bottom right corner of the page. Each digit has a block-image as 'background'.
It works in chrome, but not in IE7+ and FF..

**HTML** (I writed down only 1 digit, but there are 4):

```
<div id="container_bottom">
    <div id="counters" <div id="counter_txt">Text:</div>
    <div class="div_counter1">
        <div class="div_counter2">
            <img class="img-counter" src="counter_bg.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="div_counter3">
            <span class="counter"><?php echo $counter[1]; ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#container_bottom {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 150px;
    _width: 800px;
}
#counters {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.div_counter1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.div_counter2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.div_counter3 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 8px;
    top: 0px;
}
.counter {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#counter_txt {
    font: 16px Segoe Print;
    color: #0c3348;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 180px;
    top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, you've got some horrible browser hacks in your CSS. What versions of IE and Firefox do you need to support? You might consider dropping some of those hacks. Also, have you checked that your site doesn't put IE into quirks mode: You've not really described the problem very well, but cross browser alignment problems are often down to issues with the browser mode.

Comment: Your HTML is so badly formatted that we can't make any sense of what you are trying to do.  Please try to improve it.

Comment: I can't imagine a decent reason to be using `-moz-inline-stack`.  `inline-block` makes more sense, and it's supported in the older IE browsers with the IE7 hack you have in place.

Comment: You have an extra `</div>` at the end of your markup. I pulled it out into Notepad++ and formatted it. You should consider formatting your code better so that you can see things like that.

Comment: If you want to make a "background", try using `background` CSS property instead of an `<img />` tag.

Comment: Yes, off course!! background css property :). Thank you, I'm going to try that!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might have overcomplicated what you are trying to do seems to be something like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="container_bottom">
    <span class="counter_text">Text here:</span>
    <span class="counter_holder">0</span>
    <span class="counter_holder">0</span>
    <span class="counter_holder">0</span>
    <span class="counter_holder">6</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container_bottom{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20px;
    right:20px;
}
#container_bottom .counter_holder{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
    width:30px;
    height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    border:1px solid black;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* background-image: url('');  // add image here if needed*/
}
#container_bottom .counter_text{
 /* add css here if needed */   
}
```

[jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/y5Ab6/4/)

Comment: Yes, thank you. With the background-image property that is what I did indeed ;)

Comment: @user2182429 Please remember to select or create a correct answer to help anyone else in the future.